# UICollectionView Floating Headers on Top and Side

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header, uicollectionview, supplementary

How do you implement headers in a `UICollectionView`? I know you can put in supplementary views, but I don't know how to make them "float" above a section like headers in a `UITableView` do.

Here's my situation: I have a `collectionView` with the cells laid out in a grid format. You can scroll horizontally and vertically. I want to have a header on top so that when you scroll horizontally it scrolls horizontally with it, but it doesn't scroll vertically. I also want the same sort of thing on the left side where it scrolls vertically with the `collectionView` but not horizontally. Is implementing this with supplementary views the right approach?

The final functionality I am looking for is similar to that of the Numbers spreadsheet app on iOS.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update for iOS9:

```
let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
flow.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Pass it along.

Comment: Quick and simple. This is an even better option than having to choose between grouped/plain in UITableView. Thank you good sir.

Comment: You are great! Awesome!

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, this answer is valid, but not for multiple sections. See this blog for a better solution: http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using#notes

---

You need to specify that behaviour in your layout:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  NSMutableArray* attributesArray = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

  BOOL headerVisible = NO;

  for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray) {
    if ([attributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
      headerVisible = YES;
      attributes.frame = CGRectMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, 0, self.headerReferenceSize.width, self.headerReferenceSize.height);
      attributes.alpha = HEADER_ALPHA;
      attributes.zIndex = 2;
    }
  }

  if (!headerVisible) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                                        atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath
                                                                                                     indexPathForItem:0
                                                                                                     inSection:0]];
    [attributesArray addObject:attributes];
  }

  return attributesArray;
}
```

Comment: So setting the x-origin of the frame to "self.collectionView.contentOffset.x" will make it so it stays attached to the side of the view's frame? Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: In this case, that is correct for the x-axis. For your scenario, you'd need to duplicate with a second header that follows the y-axis.

Comment: This is a shabby hack that only works for collection views with headers for only the first section.

Comment: @shyambhat: Thanks for noticing. See this blog for a much better answer than mine: http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using#notes